# slf4j: binder not found

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

Here my dependencies:

```xml
    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I'm trying to run my application, I'm getting:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your dependency tree, especially the version of `slf4j-api`. For version 1.4.5 of `logback-classic` that should be a 2.x version, but I'm guessing you're getting a 1.x version instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed binding jar for SLF4J and Java Logging. Feel free to modify artifact version as required

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Logback is a SLF4J implementation, so you don't need a separate binding. The issue probably lies in version mismatches, the binding mechanism changed between versions 1 and 2 of SLF4J.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this link for the answer: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/solving-slf4j-failed-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder/

As part of the link, it clearly calls out the impl jar for the corresponding implementation.

> SLF4J Binding – This is either *slf4j-log4j12.jar (for log4j logging), slf4j-jdk14.jar (for Java logging), slf4j-jcl.jar (if you’re using Commons logging) or logback-classic.jar (for logback logging)*. With the correct binding jar, SLF4J is able to interface between slf4j-api and underlying logging implementation

Comment: I am actually not familiar with this subject. I got to your answer via the review queues. It was detected automatically because it was originally a link-only answer.